# why GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this) gives error in Flutter MainActivity.kt?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, plugins

GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
      net.goderbauer.flutter.contactpicker.ContactPickerPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("net.goderbauer.flutter.contactpicker.ContactPickerPlugin"));
      com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_appavailability.AppAvailability.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_appavailability.AppAvailability"));
      io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin"));
      flutter.moum.hardware_buttons.HardwareButtonsPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("flutter.moum.hardware_buttons.HardwareButtonsPlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
      com.lykhonis.simpleimagecrop.SimpleImageCropPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.lykhonis.simpleimagecrop.SimpleImageCropPlugin"));
  }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.flutterapp


import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    }
}
```

I am getting error in line

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
                                       ^
```

I tried replacing it with flutterEngine too but it didn't work.
I am actually creating an app that could run in background and for that I am using sharedPreferences. My code runs in a normal seperate project but it gives error in this one please help with this
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this in you MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.flutterapp
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(this))
    }
}
```

Hope it helps bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new FlutterEngine(this));
```

Comment: I believe the OP was using Kotlin. What's the equivalent line?